# How to reverse a string using arrays in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I wrote the following code to reverse a string in Oracle:

```
declare
  a varchar(50):='&a';
  b varchar(50);
  len number;
  i number;
begin
    len:=length(a);

    for i in reverse 1..len
    loop
        b:=b || substr(a,i,1);
    end loop;
    dbms_output.put_line('The original String is:' ||a);
    dbms_output.put_line('Reverse of String is:'||b);
end;
```

But someone specific has asked me to do the same task by using an array. Is it feasible?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yeah I stand corrected.I am using Oracle's PL/SQL.I am aware of the built in reverse() function but wouldn't be that too easy?

Comment: Well Oracle has no arrays to begin with - it has collections instead.

Comment: @JoeLove hahah no this isn't a homework.I came up with this during an ADBMS lab session.My teacher asked me to find multiple ways to reverse a string and it struck my mind that we used to use arrays to reverse a string in C or C++.I thought PL/SQL had pretty much the same syntax and structure but the main problem I am facing is how to extract each and every character from a string and store it in an array. I can promise you this isn't a homework but only curiosity.

Comment: The REVERSE() function exists for that reason. There's no point doing that manually unless maybe for the sake  of a challenge

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name oh.Actually I am pretty new to PL/SQL and wasn't aware of this fact.I guess i should take a look at collections.

Comment: @ThomasG Exactly I am taking this one up as a challenge.

Comment: Either way, I'm not against helping someone through homework either, I just take a different approach.